# What should I do about this "#version_requirements is deprecated" warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.5
```

Whenever I run `script/server` I get this warning:

```
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119: \
    Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and \
    will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
```

What can I do about it?

Should I upgrade Rails or some part of Rails?

Or is there something else I should do to address the warning?

I'm not sure what they mean by "`Use#requirement`". Where should I use it?

BTW, I'm not ready to switch to Rails 3 yet. I would have to update too many production apps and I don't have time right now. So a solution that keeps me on Rails 2.x is best.

---

My `environment.rb` file:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|

  config.gem('haml', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org')
  config.gem('fastercsv', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org')
  config.gem('ruby-net-ldap', :lib => 'net/ldap', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org')
  config.gem('paperclip', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org')
  config.gem('searchlogic', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org')

  config.action_controller.session = {
    :session_key => '_employeedata_session',
    :secret      => '...'
  }

  config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

  config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'

  config.after_initialize do
    ExceptionNotifier.exception_recipients = %w( ... )
    ExceptionNotifier.sender_address = %( ... )
    ExceptionNotifier.email_prefix = "[Employee Data app error] "
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your answer: http://www.mattvsworld.com/blog/2010/03/version_requirements-deprecated-warning-in-rails/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using the `:version` key anywhere in my gem dependencies.

Comment: @Ethan, this is a bug in your version of Rails. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error when I tried running the cucumber command.

Jacob is partially right. You also need to change the requirement method.

You need to open up the gem_dependency.rb file wherever it is located on your computer using whatever editor you like (I'm using TextMate):

mate /Users/bobby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@oddjobs/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb

Edit the file as this patch page indicates:
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/268c9040d5c3c7ed30f3923eee71a78eeece8a8a#diff-0

Worked for me, hope it helps!